# Visual Studio 2015 not showing Debug Source Files for any solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I show any of my solutions' properties and navigate to Common Properties -> Debug Source Files, all I see is the list of projects and their configurations, the same as the Configuration Properties -> Configuration settings. According to @HansPassant below, this is the Configuration Manager that's showing up in both places. As I change back and forth between the two settings, all that changes is the three controls (Configuration, Platform, "Configuration Manager...") at the top of the window are disabled when I'm in "Debug Source Files". I've provided screenshots at the bottom of the question.

I restarted Visual Studio, removed my old and new `.suo` files, and confirmed that a teammate sees the same behavior for an entirely different solution. These solutions all worked fine under 2013 and earlier. How can I get this back? It's preventing me from setting breakpoints on external code.

[image: Debug Source Files]
[image: Configuration]

**Update**

I did a repair of Visual Studio 2015, and the required system restart, and it didn't make a difference.

**Update 2**

I did a complete uninstall (which took multiple attempts, and eventually uninstalling from a system account), and reinstall, as well as installing all important (and most optional) Windows updates. There is still no difference.

Comment: The content of this dialog is completely wrong.  It is the Configuration Manager dialog, not the Solution Properties dialog.  When VS is this screwed-up then, sure, other stuff can be expected to not work correctly as well.  It is the kind of corruption that tends to require running setup with /uninstall /force to try to get the registry in good shape again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After working with Microsoft support, we landed on the solution (which I asked them to pass along as a bug): you need to install the Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015. You can modify your installation to add this, and (for me) it didn't require a machine restart.

[image: Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015 installation]

Comment: Work for me! Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I already have "Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015" for my VS Professional 2015 with Update 1 installed and still have the same problem.